# I want to add an action for pressing the Enter key (the same as for the button), in powerapps

Tags: button, powerapps, enter, lowcode

I'm creating a project in PowerApps. I need help with one functionality. I want the button and pressing the Enter key on the keyboard to perform the same action.

I am a complete beginner, I don't know how to deal with it.
This is my code:

`
loginScreen As screen:
BackgroundImage: =bg1k
ImagePosition: =ImagePosition.Fill
OnVisible: |
=Set(labeltxt,false);
Set(lblview, TextMode.Password);

```
    Container1 As groupContainer.manualLayoutContainer:
        DropShadow: =DropShadow.ExtraBold
        Fill: =RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1)
        Height: =600
        RadiusBottomLeft: =10
        RadiusBottomRight: =10
        RadiusTopLeft: =10
        RadiusTopRight: =10
        X: =450
        Y: =63
        ZIndex: =1

        personalNumbertxt As text:
            BorderThickness: =1
            Default: =""
            Height: =60
            HintText: ="Enter your personal number here"
            OnChange: |
                =
            OnSelect: =Set(labeltxt,false)
            PaddingBottom: =20
            PaddingLeft: =35
            PaddingTop: =20
            RadiusBottomLeft: =0
            RadiusBottomRight: =0
            RadiusTopLeft: =0
            RadiusTopRight: =0
            Width: =447
            X: =28
            Y: =154
            ZIndex: =1

        pintxt As text:
            BorderThickness: =1
            Default: =""
            Height: =60
            HintText: ="Enter your PIN code here"
            Mode: =lblview
            PaddingLeft: =35
            RadiusBottomLeft: =0
            RadiusBottomRight: =0
            RadiusTopLeft: =0
            RadiusTopRight: =0
            Width: =450
            X: =28
            Y: =251
            ZIndex: =2

        loginFormlbl As label:
            Align: =Align.Center
            FontWeight: =FontWeight.Bold
            Height: =50
            Size: =24
            Text: ="Login Form"
            Width: =450
            X: =25
            Y: =50
            ZIndex: =3

        incorrectlbl As label:
            Align: =Align.Center
            Color: =RGBA(118, 0, 0, 1)
            Height: =59
            Size: =11
            Text: ="Incorrect personal number or PIN!"
            Visible: =labeltxt
            Width: =450
            X: =25
            Y: =371
            ZIndex: =4

        loginbtn As button:
            Height: =43
            OnSelect: |
                =Set(
                    userrolevalue, 
                    LookUp( 
                        loginns, 
                        'Personal number' = personalNumbertxt.Text And PIN = Value(pintxt.Text)
                    )
                );
                If(
                    IsBlankOrError(userrolevalue),  //ak neplatí
                    Notify("Incorrect Username or Password");
                    Set(labeltxt, true),
                    Navigate(categoryScreen)   //ak platí
                );
                Reset(personalNumbertxt); //po overení užívateľa!! čiže akokoľvek 
                Reset(pintxt);
            RadiusBottomLeft: =5
            RadiusBottomRight: =5
            RadiusTopLeft: =5
            RadiusTopRight: =5
            Text: ="Login"
            Width: =239
            X: =130
            Y: =456
            ZIndex: =5

        iconUser As icon.AddUser:
            Color: =RGBA(102, 102, 102, 1)
            Height: =60
            Icon: =Icon.AddUser
            PaddingLeft: =7
            Width: =25
            X: =28
            Y: =154
            ZIndex: =6

        iconView As icon.View:
            Color: =RGBA(128, 128, 128, 1)
            Height: =36
            Icon: =Icon.View
            OnSelect: =Set(lblview,TextMode.SingleLine)
            PaddingRight: =10
            Width: =36
            X: =426
            Y: =263
            ZIndex: =7

        iconLock As icon.Lock:
            Color: =RGBA(128, 128, 128, 1)
            Height: =60
            Icon: =Icon.Lock
            PaddingLeft: =7
            Width: =25
            X: =28
            Y: =251
            ZIndex: =8
```

`

Comment: I think "Enter key" functionality is not supported in Power Apps by default. Check this for possible workarounds: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Submit-Form-with-the-Enter-Key/td-p/835008?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I have added it as an answer below with some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, "Enter key" functionality is not supported in Microsoft Power Apps by default.

There are few workarounds to get it working as mentioned in this thread, [Power Apps - Submit Form with the Enter Key](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Submit-Form-with-the-Enter-Key/td-p/835008?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224):

> *You can first hit the "Tab" key multiple times until the "Submit" button is selected, and then hit "Enter" to trigger this button and submit the form.*

[image]

---

> The Tab key should navigate to interactive elements in a logical order. You can create this with a [logical app structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/accessible-apps-structure#logical-control-order?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) and by setting each control's [TabIndex property](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/properties-accessibility?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) accordingly.

**Source**: [Create accessible canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/accessible-apps?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#keyboard)